# El registro obtenido en un SELECT al asignar valores a variables siempre es el último registro encontrado, sin respetar el orden

Tags: sql-server, variables, select

En ocasiones es necesario realizar la asignación de valores a una *variable* dentro de un *SELECT* ésto mediante una instrucción de ésta manera:

```
SELECT @id = ID, @title = TITLE, @category = CATEGORY 
    FROM #TMPLIST WHERE CATEGORY = 'F'  
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Teniendo en cuenta que para el ejemplo en una *tabla temporal* y *variables* como se muestra enseguida:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMPLIST (ID INT, TITLE NVARCHAR(20), CATEGORY NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (1,N'MANZANA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (2,N'PERA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (3,N'NARANJA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (4,N'BANANA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (5,N'CEBOLLA',N'V')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (5,N'ACELGAS',N'V')

declare @id int, @title nvarchar(20), @category nvarchar(1)
```

El resultado (o los registros) que siempre logro obtener, cuando hay mas de un resultado siempre es el último o bien en un orden descendente.

Es decir, en el *SELECT* sin asignación de variables tendría el siguiente resultado:

```
ID          TITLE                CATEGORY
----------- -------------------- --------
1           MANZANA              F
2           PERA                 F
3           NARANJA              F
4           BANANA               F
```

Pero cuando asigno valor a las variables obtengo en éste ejemplo el último es decir el ID=4

```
ID          TITLE                CATEGORY
----------- -------------------- --------
4           BANANA               F
```

**Sin embargo el resultado esperado es ID=1 siendo éste en teoría forzado por el ordenamiento de los resultados.**

Aquí dejo el script completo usado para el ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMPLIST (ID INT, TITLE NVARCHAR(20), CATEGORY NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (1,N'MANZANA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (2,N'PERA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (3,N'NARANJA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (4,N'BANANA',N'F')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (5,N'CEBOLLA',N'V')
INSERT INTO #TMPLIST VALUES (5,N'ACELGAS',N'V')

declare @id int, @title nvarchar(20), @category nvarchar(1)


SELECT * FROM #TMPLIST WHERE CATEGORY = 'F' ORDER BY ID ASC



SELECT @id = ID, @title = TITLE, @category = CATEGORY 
    FROM #TMPLIST WHERE CATEGORY = 'F'  
    ORDER BY ID ASC

SELECT @id AS ID, @title AS TITLE, @category AS CATEGORY


if EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'#TMPLIST'))
    drop table #TMPLIST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El resultado que obtienes es el último registro del `SELECT`, cada registro, en el orden establecido, va sobrescribiendo el valor de las variables, como ordenas ascendente, el último es justamente el 5.

Para lo que buscas deberías ordenar `DESC`

```
SELECT @id = ID, @title = TITLE, @category = CATEGORY 
    FROM #TMPLIST WHERE CATEGORY = 'F'  
    ORDER BY ID DESC
```

O incluso mejor, agregando un `TOP` para retornar una única fila usando en este caso el orden ascendente ya que aquí si el primer registro va a ser el único.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @id = ID, @title = TITLE, @category = CATEGORY 
    FROM #TMPLIST WHERE CATEGORY = 'F'  
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: Gracias @sstan, editado.

Comment: Tiene lógica tu respuesta acerca de sobrescribir las variables, definitivamente es un tema que requiero conocer más de fondo la lógica interna de las transacciones de SQL Server.

De las dos opciones, la que pude aplicar fue la de `TOP 1... ASC` ya que en cambiando el orden a DESC simple, no me arroja el valor deseado.

Gracias @Patricio